# If a matrix has algebraically equivalent rows is it not invertible by definition?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, proof-verification

For matrix A=\begin{bmatrix}a&b\\c&d\end{bmatrix}
Show that if ad-bc=0, then the equation Ax=0 has more than one solution. Why does this imply that A is not invertible?
My solution was to say:
\begin{bmatrix}ad&bd\\bc&bd\end{bmatrix} then say ad=bc so...
\begin{bmatrix}bc&bd\\bc&bd\end{bmatrix} 
Because the top row is equivalent to the bottom row it is not invertible. 
My question is it possible for you to be able to set the top and bottom of a matrix to algebraically equivalent values and it still be invertible? Is there a proof showing this is not the case? My professor said because I did not think about the possibility of d or b being zero (scalar multiplication times zero is not allowed) it was incorrect. I believe it is impossible for it to be the case that a matrix top row and bottom row could be set to the same algebraic values and and it be invertible, I appreciate any input.
(Specifically it must be done without saying/assuming the values are zero) or else some one could take any arbitrary matrix and say a=0 multiply all rows by a then say all values are a.

Note: The real solution was if a=0 b or c must be zero. so the matrix can not be put into rref so not invertible and the same phenomenon happens if any of the other variables are set to zero. Base on the equation ad=bc

Comment: If $AX=0$ has two solutions, then $A$, considered as a function mapping vectors to vectors, is not one-to-one, so it cannot have an inverse.

Comment: The question asks us to show how ad=bc implies AX=0 for the above matrixes.

Comment: Your question says, "Why does this imply that A is not invertible?"  That's the only question I see here.

Comment: What is your second matrix (with both elements $bd$ in the 2nd column)?

Comment: I multiplied R1 by d and R2 by b. That is why my professor took issue because my solution involved multiplying rows by a variable that could be zero, which is not allowed.